# Parse a string as a (long long) integer

Tags: c, long-long

I am writing a code in which I need to parse a string to a "long long int"

I used to use atoi when changing from string to int, I dont think it still work. What Can I use now?

--Thanks

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is "parse a string as a (long long) integer". Leave "change" to the politicians :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `strtoll()` ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll)):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

long long int n = strtoll(s, NULL, 0);
```

(This is only available in C99 and C11, not in C89.) The third argument is the number base for the conversion, and `0` means "automatic", i.e. decimal, octal or hexadecimal are selected depending on the usual conventions (`10`, `010`, `0x10`). Just be mindful of that in case your string starts with `0`.

Comment: 100% correct, but two warnings: First, the automatic base can be confusing, because 010 is 8 (obvious to some, absurd for others). Second, it doesn't really do error checking. So "7up" becomes 7, and "hello" becomes 0.